# How to explode a struct index in pandas series

Tags: pandas, struct, series, multi-index, pandas-explode

I have a pandas Series where the index is a StructType. I want to explode this index into the structfields.

| index | value |
| --- | --- |
| (2005-07-03, beta0) | 0.997160 |
| (2005-07-03, beta1) | 0.037629 |
| (2005-07-03, beta2) | 0.037629 |
| (2005-07-03, tau) | 2.000000 |
| (2011-11-13, beta0) | 0.997160 |

Here the index is of the structype key: struct<checkin_week:date,parameter:string>

I need to explode it two columns such that I have a column for checkin_week and another column for parameter.

Comment: copy paste part of your serie in your question

Comment: The series is already copy pasted above @khaledkoubaa

Comment: it's a picture, it needs to be text format

Comment: @khaledkoubaa : I changed it to a text format. Not sure why is it that important to answer the question. Could you please explain.

Comment: you need to split this ```(2005-07-03, beta0)``` to ```2005-07-03``` and ```2005-07-03```? I mean split in 2 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will give you a `DataFrame` with a `MultiIndex`, in which `checkin_week` and `parameter` will be separate levels.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=(
        0.997160,
        0.037629,
        0.037629,
        2.000000,
        0.997160,
    ),
    index=(
        ("2005-07-03", "beta0"),
        ("2005-07-03", "beta1"),
        ("2005-07-03", "beta2"),
        ("2005-07-03", "tau"),
        ("2011-11-13", "beta0"),
    ),
)

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index)
```

If you want them to be separate columns (instead of indexes), you should first reset your `DataFrame`'s index:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=False)
```

And then follow the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/split-a-pandas-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)